# Reduce runtime of for loop using comprehensive list

Tags: python, list, runtime, bigdata, list-comprehension

I have got two lists:

```
List1 ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we']
List2 =  ['i am legend', 'its me time', 'my book is red ', 'i told myself', 'we are thinking about we']
```

I wanna check the number of times an element of List1 has occurred in List2.

```
count = 0
occurance = []
for row in range(len(List1 )):
   for item in range(len(List2 )):
       if List1 [row] in List2 [item]:
           count += 1 
   occurance.append(count)
   count = 0
result = list(zip(occurance,List1))
```

This code is working and the result is
[(5, 'i'), (1, 'me'), (2, 'my'), (1, 'myself'), (1, 'we')]

**Problem:**

Size of List2 in real-world is *82 million*. Runtime is high, and I need to reduce it.
I read articles that using a ***comprehensive list*** could help to reduce the execution time.

**My questions**

1. How to convert this code to ***comprehensive list***?
2. Do you recommend any other method to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have 5 matches for "i"?

Comment: @antimon 
Yes, This is just an example. For loops are the main question

Answer (score 0):

I would use a comprehensive dictionary, but I cannot make it fully work. It would like:

```
x = {k:[List2.count(l)] for l in List2 for k in List1}
```

From this point is really easy to move to a list of tuples.

```
y = [(k, v) for k, v in x.items()]
```

Comment: It doesn't have the if statement